# Why does xargs seem to handle delimiters differently if -I is set

Tags: shell, xargs, echo

`xargs -n1 -I '{}' echo '{}'  <<< "foo bar baz"` prints
`foo bar baz`

while `xargs -n1 echo <<< "foo bar baz"` prints

```
foo
bar
baz
```

What causes this behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specifying `-I` [changes the separator](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/xargs.html):

> **-I** *replstr*
>
> Arguments in the standard input shall be separated only by unescaped <newline> characters, not by <blank> characters.

In your second example, the spaces between `foo`, `bar` and `baz` split the input; but in your first, the input is treated as a single unit since it’s a single line.

Comment: Is there a way I can make -I not do that?

Comment: No, but you can work around it: `xargs -n1 <<<"foo bar baz" | xargs -I '{}' echo '{}'`.